# multivariable function maximum

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> $max\Bigl\{\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^{2}:\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}=1,x_{i}>\lambda,i=1,...n\Bigl\}= \\
> max\Bigl\{\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}x_{i}^{2}+(1-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}x_{i})^{2} : \sum_{i=1}^{n-1}x_{i} \leq 1-\lambda,x_{i}\geq\lambda, i=1,...,n-1 \Bigl\}= \\
> (n-1)\lambda^{2}+(1-(n-1)\lambda)^{2}$

Any idea how to solve this? I tried Lagrange multipliers in both braces. The first one returns critical point at 1/n while the second at $\frac{1-\lambda}{n-1}$.

edit. $(1-\frac{2}{n})\frac{1}{n-1}<\lambda<\frac{1}{n}$

$\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^{2}=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}x_{i}^{2}+x_{n}^{2}=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}x_{i}^{2}+(1-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}x_{i})^{2}$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: What is $l$? Why do you have two maximums on either side of an equation?

Comment: It's the same function in both braces with different constraints. The second one is supposed to make the problem solvable.

Comment: So is $l$ supposed to be $\lambda$?

Comment: Yes it is, my bad. I fixed it